# "Error: No layers in plot" when using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got a simple data.frame (AD0) with basic statistical values and the factor(group):

```
       mean         se        sd median group
value1 0.725 0.07149951 0.4522026      1     1
value2 0.650 0.07637626 0.4830459      1     2
value3 0.175 0.06084343 0.3848076      0     3
value4 0.375 0.07752171 0.4902903      0     4
```

I tried to make a simple barplot with:

```
p <- ggplot(AD0, aes(mean,group)) + geom_bar()
```

However, I get the message: "Error: No layers in plot" 
It is such a simple thing and I can't get my head around why its not working.

I would be really glad if somebody could help me

Comment: I get a different error, but in any case, try adding `stat = "identity"` to `geom_bar`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have presummarised data, you need to specify `stat = "identity"` in `geom_bar`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(AD0, aes(group, mean)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Furthermore, I suppose you want to use `group` for the x-axis and `mean` for the y-axis. I switched the order of both names.

[image]